# Phonegap push notification android, need opinion

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I'm currently developing android apps using phonegap + jquery mobile. I need to add notification bar in my application. Currently, I'm using [Notification phonegap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification) to handle notification. But it didn't send notification when application closed. Is there any solution to keep my user recieve notification even application is closed? Can I use [Google Cloud Messanging](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html) to solve it?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Comment: yes, theres a GCM Phonegap Plugin on Github: https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Comment: can I use gcm to make push notification even my app closed?

Comment: yes. GCM Messages are initialized by a remote server. You will have to set it up yourself. Your server will inform the google servers that an event happened, the google servers will push the message to the device. look it up, it´s all very well documented: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I`ll look forward it. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use push notifications. The following plugin handles both Android and iPhone notifications:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

A notification will be shown whenever a push message is received and it contains a **message** attribute.